# for update code in same page need ajax or else?

Tags: php, javascript, html

when i press on *edit* link on **detail.php** it will show me **data.php** page with data filled in form... now if i want to edit something then press edit **button** it would be update.. code of data.php is given as below

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name'])):?>
<script>
window.onload=function()
{
document.getElementById("sbmt").style.visibility="hidden";

};              
function editform()
{
```

**i need code at this place** _what should it be?? i guess i need ajax. when i press edit button it would be edit record i tried below something like below bt for that i need value name=???  how can i get that value _

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
   // mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE user_detail SET     name=,address=,gender=,hoby=,country=,place=,
    //WHERE name='$_GET['name']'");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
};                          
</script>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$p= $_GET['name'];
//echo "$p";
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_detail where name ='$p' ");
$data =mysqli_fetch_array($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
<?php else:?>
<script>
window.onload=function()
{
document.getElementById("edit").style.visibility="hidden";

};
</script>

    <?php $data =array();?>
<?php endif;?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['txt_user'])) {
header('Location: Login.php');
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Form with Validation </title>

<script language="JavaScript">
var flag=0;
var file_selected = false;
var file_selected1 = false;

function validform()
{
    var x=document.forms["form1"]["tname"].value;//Name
    var y=document.forms["form1"]["address"].value;//Address

    if (x==null || x=="")
    {   
        flag = 1;

        document.getElementById('tn').value="Please! Enter name ";
        //alert("Please Enter Name:");
        //return false;
    }
    else
    {
        flag=0;
    }
    if (y==null || y==" ")
    {   
        flag=flag+1;
        document.getElementById('ta').innerHTML="Please! Enter address ";

        //alert("Please Enter Address");
        //return false;
    }
    else
    {
        flag=0;
    }
    if ((form1.gender[0].checked == false) && (form1.gender[1].checked == false))
    {
        flag +=1;
        document.getElementById('gne').innerHTML="Please! Select gender ";  
        //alert("Pleae Select Gender");
        //return false;
    }
    else
    {
        flag =0;
        document.getElementById('gne').innerHTML="";
    }
    if (form1.hobby.checked == false && form1.hobby.checked == false && form1.hobby.checked == false) 
    {
        flag +=1;
        document.getElementById('hbe').innerHTML="Please! Select hobby ";
        //alert ('Please!!!, Select any hobby!');
        //return false;
    } 
    else
    {
        flag =0;
        document.getElementById('hbe').innerHTML="";
    }
    var psel=document.getElementById('fp'); //Favourite place
    var valid = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < psel.options.length; i++) {
        if(psel.options[i].selected) {
            valid = true;

            break;
        }
    }
    if(valid==false)
    {
        flag +=1;
        document.getElementById('fp_error').innerHTML="Please! Select Any Favourite Place ";
        //return false;
        //  alert("Please! Select Any Favourite Place ");
    }
    else
    {
            flag =0;
            document.getElementById('fp_error').innerHTML="";
    }
    if(!file_selected)
    {
        flag +=1;
        document.getElementById('f_pic').innerHTML="Please! Select Any Picture ";
        //alert('Please Select any Picture');
        //return false;
    }
    else
    {
        flag =0;
        document.getElementById('f_pic').innerHTML="";
    }
    if(!file_selected1)
    {
        flag +=1;
        document.getElementById('f_doc').innerHTML="Please! Select Document";
        //alert('Please Select any Document');
            //return false;
    }
    else
    {
        flag =0;
    }

    if(flag ==0)
    {
        document.getElementById('data_form').action = "Data_con.php";  
        document.getElementById('data_form').submit();

    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
function Logout()
{
document.getElementById('data_form').action = "Logout.php";
}

</script>
</head>
<body> 
<!--onsubmit="return validform()"-->
<form id="data_form" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">

<table align="center" border="2">

<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><input id="tn" type="text" name="tname" <?php if($data['name']):?>value="<?php echo $data['name'];?>" <?php endif;?>></td>

<!--<td id="tne"></td>-->
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Address:</td>

<td><textarea id= "ta" rows="3" cols="16" name="address" > 
<?php echo $data['address'];?>
</textarea> </td>
<!--<td id="tae"></td>-->
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Gender:</td>


<?php 
    $x=$data['gender'];
?>
<td> <input type="radio" id="gn" name="gender" value="male" <?php if($x=='male'):?> checked<?php endif;?> >  Male
<input type="radio" id="gn" name="gender" value="female" <?php if($x=='female'):?> checked<?php endif;?> > Female
</td>
<td id="gne"></td>
</tr>




<tr>
<td>Hobby:</td>
<?php
$y=$data['hoby'];
?>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="hockey" <?php if($y=='hockey'):?> checked='checked';<?php endif;?>> Hockey
<input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="reading" <?php if($y=='reading'):?> checked='checked';<?php endif;?>> Reading<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="traveling" <?php if($y=='traveling'):?> checked='checked';<?php endif;?>> Traveling
<br>
</td>
<td id="hbe"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Country: </td>
<?php
$z=$data['country'];
?>
<td>
<select name="helo" id="hl">
<option value="germany"<?php if($z=='germany'):?> selected<?php endif;?> >Germany </option>
<option value="india" <?php if($z=='india'):?> selected <?php endif;?> >India </option>
<option value="japan" <?php if($z=='japan'):?> selected<?php endif;?> >Japan </option>
</select>
</td>
<td id="hle"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Favourite Place:</td>
<?php
$w  =$data['place'];
?>
<td>
<select id="fp"  name="place" multiple="multiple">
<option value="ahmedabad" <?php if($w=='ahmedabad'):?> selected<?php endif;?> >Ahmedabad</option>
<option value="nadiad" <?php if($w=='nadiad'):?> selected<?php endif;?> >Nadiad</option>
<option value="anand" <?php if($w=='anand'):?> selected<?php endif;?> >Anand</option>
<option value="vadodara" <?php if($w=='vadodara'):?> selected<?php endif;?> >Vadodara</option>
<option value="surat" <?php if($w=='surat'):?> selected<?php endif;?> >Surat</option>
</select>
</td>
<td id="fp_error"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Photo:</td>
<td><input type="file" onchange="file_selected=true;" name="pic"  ></td>
<td id="f_pic"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>Resume:</td>
<td><input type="file" onchange="file_selected1=true;" name="doc" ></td>
<td id="f_doc"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><center>
    <input type="Submit" id="edit" value="edit" Name="Edit" onclick="editform();"> 
    <input type="button" id="sbmt" value="Submit" Name="Submit" onclick="validform();">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" Name="Submit" onclick="Logout();">
<center></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks friend...

Comment: you definitely need ajax

Comment: ya, i know bt what it is placed? i dont know how to use ajax :(

Comment: this [PHP MYSQL AJAX tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) will get you started. If you get stuck somewhere, let me know.

Comment: Its fairly easy, don't worry, you'll get through.

Comment: should i need to take another page for php??? i want to in same page//

Comment: yeah create another PHP page which will connect to MYSQL, perform queries and then echo out the desired result as an AJAX response.